# Less file compilation

Tags: css, less

I have the less file to cover my entire application styles. But I use some old standard for assign the value for the variable in initial time, based on theme color switch the variable value can be updated.

In initially

```
@theme =""

(~"@{theme}.ss-slidebar:before") {
     font-size: 23px;
     margin-top: -3px;
}
```

Since my project deployment time I use the dotless compiler will compile this LESS styles to generate the corresponding CSS. But my unsolved questions are listed below.

1. When I'm trying to compile my LESS files in other compiler like as web essential will throws the error.

   **ParseError: unrecognized input on line 1, column 3:**

   (~"@{theme}.ss-slidebar:before")
2. Or use the online compiler http://less2css.org/ also throws the below error.

   **ParseError: Missing closing ')' on line 1, column 3:**

   (~"@{theme}.ss-slidebar:before")

I will struct this issues, if there is any other ways to resolve this issues, or any other ways for change my variable substitution to achieve my scenario in generic way for all compilers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which error occurs? You didn't mention anyone.

Comment: That kind of syntax was deprecated a while ago so you should been using pretty outdated `dotless` version for it to work. The valid Less syntax in this case is just `@{theme}.ss-slidebar:before` w/o any parens and quotes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your valuable response. I also got the deprecated information from the LESS library change log page. **https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md**  in the versoin **1.4.0 Beta 1 & 2**   (~"@var") selector interpolation is removed. Use @{var} in selectors to have variable selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments have stated you have syntax errors:

- Missing `;` on variable declaration
- No need for parentheses or string declarations

---

```
@theme : ;

@{theme}.ss-slidebar:before {
     font-size: 23px;
     margin-top: -3px;
}
```